# How to explicitly check if there is an index in an array

Tags: laravel

I have an array that looks like this

```
array [
    'product1' => [
        'product_amount' => 123,
    ],
    'product2' => [
        'product_amount_price' => 123
    ]
]
```

The issue I'm having is that I need to check if only `product_amount_price` is in the array, and if it is then do one thing otherwise do something else.

```
if(in_array('product_amount_price', $productArr))
{
    $productAmount = $productArr['product_amount_price'];
}else{
    $productAmount = $productArr['product_amount'];
}

dd($productAmount);
```

And what happens is if I land up on a product that has `product_amount` I get this error

> Undefined index: product_amount_price

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop the array first, then use the `in_array()` method for each of the element, something like this:

```
foreach ($productArr as $product) {
    $productAmount = $product['product_amount_price'] ?? $product['product_amount'];
    //...
}
```

You need to make a loop first because the `product_amount_price` property is not on the first layer of your array, but the second.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had to use `array_key_exists` and not `in_array`

Comment: using the operator `??` is easier. check the edited answer of @felixbmmm